# advanced coin tossing probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that a fair coin is tossed until a head is obtained, and that this
entire experiment is then performed a second time. Find the probability that
the second experiment requires more tosses than the ﬁrst experiment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X$ and $Y$ represent the numbers of tosses. The probability that $X=n$ is $\frac{1}{2^n}$, so the probability that $X=n$ and $Y=n$ is $\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$. Add up, $1$ to $\infty$. We get $\frac{1}{3}$.

The remaining $\frac{2}{3}$ is evenly split between $X\gt Y$ and $X\lt Y$.

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, the probability that the first requires more tosses is equal to the probability that the second requires more. Therefore you just need to find the probability that they both require the same number of tosses, which can be done by hand pretty easily.